# installing ecdsa

Tags: installation, python

how do i install ecdsa? im getting this error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ electrum
Error: python-ecdsa does not seem to be installed. Try 'sudo pip install ecdsa'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip install ecdsa
Downloading/unpacking ecdsa
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ecdsa
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 3, in 
    ImportError: No module named setuptools.command
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 3, in 

ImportError: No module named setuptools.command
```

---

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in ./pip-log.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: doesnt help at all.. im talking beginner answer here

Answer (score 3):

First,

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Second,

`sudo easy_install pip`

Third,

`sudo pip install ecdsa`

and then

`electrum`

Comment: thefourtheye again to the rescue, you sir are a true master

Comment: Thanks @user152948. Hope your python-central also is working fine. Would mind accepting this answer and the python-central answer as well?